# Elixir how to emulate nested comprehensions

Tags: elixir

```
def letterCombinations(text) do
  dict = %{"2" => ["a","b","c"], "3" => ["d","e","f"], "4" => ["g","h","i"], "5" => ["j","k","l"], "6" => ["m","n","o"], "7" => ["p","q","r"], "8" => ["s","t","u"],"9" => "vwx"}
  numbers = String.codepoints(text)
  test1 = dict["2"]
  test2 = dict["3"]
  test3 = dict["4"]
  for tst1 <- test1, tst2 <- test2,tst3 <- test3 do
    "#{tst1}#{tst2}#{tst3}"
  end

 end
```

Imagine an old cell phone, the buttons had a set of 3 letters.
I want to make a function that would return all the possible combinations of letters.(The letters are assigned starting from the number 2)
Example

```
letterCombination("23")
```

would return

```
 ["ad" ,"ae" ,"af" ,"bd" ,"be" ,"bf" ,"cd" ,"ce" ,"cf"]
```

The input was "23", therefore I expect the output to be all the messages of length 2 that you could have got by selecting one of the available letters for each number in that order.
In the function above you can see the mappings and the idea of what I try to accomplish.
The problem is that I don't know how to do it without nested comprehensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the input is only two characters, you can use the [`<<>>` bitstring operator](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#%3C%3C%3E%3E/1) to match the two values, and then it becomes a simple comprehension with two generators:

```elixir
def letterCombination(<<key1::binary-1, key2::binary-1>>) do
  for l1 <- @keypad[key1], l2 <- @keypad[key2], do: l1 <> l2
end
```

---

If you want to be more general and accept any length of input, then as Silvio Mayolo pointed out a single comprehension is not enough, you need to use recursion. This is mostly a simplified example of  Silvio's answer, adjusted to take advantage of the bitstring operator in the function header.

```elixir
def letterCombination(""), do: [""]

def letterCombination(<<key::binary-1, rest::binary>>) do
  for letter <- @keypad[key], tail <- letterCombination(rest), do: letter <> tail
end
```

Usage:

```elixir
iex(1)> Example.letterCombination("234")
["adg", "adh", "adi", "aeg", "aeh", "aei", "afg", "afh", "afi", "bdg", "bdh",
 "bdi", "beg", "beh", "bei", "bfg", "bfh", "bfi", "cdg", "cdh", "cdi", "ceg",
 "ceh", "cei", "cfg", "cfh", "cfi"]
```

---

Note I defined the keypad in a module attribute like this:

```elixir
@keypad %{ "2" => ["a", "b", "c"],  "3" => ["d", "e", "f"], ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, when you find yourself wanting to nest `for` comprehensions N layers deep based on an argument, you're probably looking to write a recursive function instead. We can convert your `letter_combinations` function into a recursive one with the base case being "empty string". In the recursive case, we'll take the first character and then recursively call our function on the remainder of the string. Each individual iteration of the function only does two `for` comprehensions, but the overall recursion can do several.

```
def letter_combinations(text) do
  if text == "" do
    [""]
  else
    dict = %{"2" => ["a","b","c"], "3" => ["d","e","f"], "4" => ["g","h","i"], "5" => ["j","k","l"], "6" => ["m","n","o"], "7" => ["p","q","r"], "8" => ["s","t","u"],"9" => "vwx"}
    head = String.slice(text, 0..0)
    tail = String.slice(text, 1..-1)
    headtest = dict[head]
    tailtest = letter_combinations(tail)
    for x <- headtest, xs <- tailtest do
      "#{x}#{xs}"
    end
  end
end
```

Example usage:

```
IO.inspect(A.letter_combinations "223")
```